# Solution to transcendental equation from Mathematica and Python do not match

Tags: python, numpy, wolfram-mathematica, root

I am solving a system of transcendental equations:

1. `cos(x) / x = 0.48283 + a*3.46891`
2. `cos(y) / y = 0.47814 + b*28.6418`
3. `a + b = 1`
4. `1.02 * sinc(x) = 1.03 * sinc(y)`

And it just so happens I tried to solve the above system in two separated programming languages (Mathematica and Python)

### Mathematica

Running the code

```
FindRoot[{Cos[x]/x == 0.482828 + a*3.46891, 
  Cos[y]/y == 0.47814 + b*28.6418, a + b == 1, 
  1.02*Sinc[x] == 1.03*Sinc[y]}, {{x, .2}, {y, .2}, {a, 0.3}, {b, 
   0.3}}, PrecisionGoal -> 6]
```

returns

```
{x -> 0.261727, y -> 0.355888, a -> 0.924737, b -> 0.0752628}
```

### Python

Running the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root

def fuuu(X, en,dv,tri,sti):
        x, y, a, b = X

        F = [np.cos(x) / x - en-a*dv,
             np.cos(y) / y - tri-b*sti,
             a + b - 1,
             1.02 * np.sinc(x) - 1.03 * np.sinc(y)]

        return F
    root(fuuu, [0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3], args=(0.482828,3.46891,0.47814,28.6418)).x
```

returns

```
array([ 0.26843418,  0.27872813,  0.89626625,  0.10373375])
```

### Comparison

Let's say that the 'x' value is the same. Let's just ignore the small difference. But the y values differ by miles! The physical meaning completely changes. For some reason I believe the values from Mathematica more than I believe values from Python.

Questions:

1. Why do the calculations differ?
2. Which one is now correct? What do I have to change in python (assuming python is the problematic one)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The calculation differ because of the `sinc` function.

```
(* Mathematica *)
In[1] := Sinc[0.26843418]
Out[1] = 0.988034

# Python
>>> np.sinc(0.26843418)
0.88561519683835599
>>> np.sin(0.26843418) / 0.26843418
0.98803370932709034
```

Huh? Well [let's RTFM](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sinc.html)

> #### numpy.sinc(x)
>
> Return the sinc function.
>
> The sinc function is sin(πx)/(πx).

Oops. NumPy's `sinc` has a [different definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) than Mathematica's `Sinc`.

- Mathematica's `Sinc` uses the *unnormalized* definition sin(x)/x. This definition is usually used in mathematics and physics.
- NumPy's `sinc` uses the *normalized* version sin(πx)/(πx). This definition is usually used in digital signal processing and information theory. It is called normalized because
  ∫<sub>-∞</sub><sup>∞</sup> sin(πx)/(πx) dx = 1.

Therefore, if you want NumPy to produce the same result as Mathematica, you need to divide `x` and `y` by `np.pi`.

```
def fuuu(X, en,dv,tri,sti):
    x, y, a, b = X
    F = [np.cos(x) / x - en-a*dv,
         np.cos(y) / y - tri-b*sti,
         a + b - 1,
         1.02 * np.sinc(x/np.pi) - 1.03 * np.sinc(y/np.pi)]    # <---
    return F
```

```
>>> root(fuuu, [0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3], args=(0.482828,3.46891,0.47814,28.6418)).x
array([ 0.26172691,  0.3558877 ,  0.92473722,  0.07526278])
```

Comment: sweet! Thank you.

Comment: Please add this line as well. In mathematics, `sinc` refers to unnormalized version. Hence, sinc(x) = sin(x) / x.  

Numpy uses normalized version. Easy to remember. Hence, `sinc(x) = sin(pi * x) / (pi. x)`

Comment: @kmario23 done. It is actually explained in the linked wikipedia article.

Comment: @kennytm Thanks, now the answer looks elegant. I requested to add it here for completeness (the answer by itself)